# Extract page number from a link to a pdf using python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to find the page number that a link to a PDF point to. This link is in another PDF file. I've succesfully managed to get all the link in a pdf using the annotations but these link point to the whole file and not the specific page. Do you know of a way of doing that in python or another language ?

Comment: Welcome. It will be good to share at least name of module you're using to work with pdf.

Comment: I've been using PyPDF2 in python 3.4.